# Does $x^4-x \in (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]$ split completely?

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field

I know that $x^4-x \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ splits completely and is separable, but I'm not sure what the answer is for $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]$. It seems that it should obviously be that the polynomial doesn't split and isn't separable. But since only $0,1 \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and these are roots of the polynomial, I'm not sure what the answer is.

Also, in the definition of splitting (for a polynomial), is the only difference for the definition is separability that we allow the constants to be nondistinct?

Comment: $x^4-x=x(x^3-1)=x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, and the last factor has no roots in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This factors as
$$x(x^3-1)=x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$$
But the latter factor is irreducible. The polynomial is separable though. $x^2+x+1$ doesn't have a repeated root because it can't be written as $(x-a)^2$, and neither root is equal to $0$ or $1$.

Comment: So the polynomial doesn't split in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ but is separable? In general, is any polynomial $f$ with $\text{deg}(f)$ distinct roots separable in any field, but doesn't necessarily split in that field?

Comment: @Monzur Having distinct roots in one field doesn't mean it will have distinct roots in another characteristic. $x^2-1$ is separable in $\mathbb Q$ but not in $\mathbb Z_2$.